# sequelize, date is returned as 1 day plus

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my node project,  I am using Sequelize to connect the Mysql database.

When I send the response, date field shows 1 day plus.

Any idea why it is like this?

> Response:

```
[
   {
         'name': 'MMK',
         'entryDate': '2019-02-12'
   }
]
```

> Mysql Database has

```
name: 'MMK', entryDate: '2019-20-11'
```

> Model

```
EntryDate: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      get: function() {
        if(this.getDataValue('EntryDate') != null) {
          return moment.utc(this.getDataValue('EntryDate')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        } else {
          return this.getDataValue('EntryDate');
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Your database timezone offset doesn't match your application timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to adjust the date using utc? see the section of utc vs timezone here https://momentjs.com/guides/ I think removing the utc adjustment will give you the correct date.